# What is Shotwell doing in background permanently

Tags: nautilus, process, shotwell

My mate is a new ubuntu user, primarily as alternative to not need to upgrade to windows 10. He uses his machine mainly for archiving and reworking of hundreds of photos as he is a hobby photographer.

Although he doesn't use shotwell for anything, shotwell is running in the background the whole time and slowing down the system.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                             
 4503 midnats+  20   0 1477504 137380  17296 D  29,9  3,4   4:18.56 shotwell
```

I can't figure out what is going on and why the system gets so slow other than that, so heres the question, what is done by shotwell and how can I stop it? I did even disable the nautilus preview function for local files, but that does not seem to work either.

Comment: `killall shotwell` to kill it, no idea about why it takes so much CPU. But running in background kind of makes sense to me, so it can be instantly opened when you click on an image.

Comment: I deinstalled it, since not used. But this is for what is it doing. On my system opening shotwell takes long every time.

Comment: @BeowulfOF, you may check Edit > Preferences > Library if the Watch function is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

`shotwell` is a photos management tool and also can be used for `Desktop Background` or `Desktop Slideshow` . As you are saying process running continuously so, it might be you set Background photos using `shotwell`.

**solution:**
if you don't want to use `shotwell` then  remove shotwell package using command

```
sudo apt-get purge shotwell
```